# .Net Core XSLT transform throws exception "Invalid XML character". But on .Net Framework works fine

Tags: c#, xml, docker, xslt, .net-core

I'm trying transform XML using `XsltCompiledTransform`. On my local PC it works fine. But in docker container sometimes `XsltCompiledTransform.Transform()` throws.

Full error

```
System.ArgumentException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteElementTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlRawWriterWrapper.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryOutput.StartCopy(XPathNavigator navigator, Boolean callChk)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryOutput.CopyNode(XPathNavigator navigator)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryOutput.WriteItem(XPathItem item)
   at <xsl:template name="compiler:generated"> (2)(XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator , String , String , String , IList`1 , String )
   at <xsl:template name="compiler:generated">(XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator )
   at <xsl:template match="/">(XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator )
   at Root(XmlQueryRuntime )
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlSequenceWriter results)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(XmlReader input, XmlWriter results)
   at XsltTranslator.Translate(Byte[] report)
```

The XSLT file is valid. And the XML is valid. I'm sure because this code sometimes works in docker, and always works fine on Windows or Linux OS with the same files.

I've tried to disable character checking in settings but anyway not working.

If I run the code on local PC on Windows or Linux OS everything works fine. Also on .Net Framework everything works.

My code:

```cs
public byte[] Translate(byte[] report)
{
    byte[] result;

    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
    var xsltTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

    var version = GetVersion(report, encoding);
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(encoding.GetString(report))))
    using (var writerStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(writerStream, new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = encoding }))
    {
        xsltTransform.Load(Path.Combine(shemesPath, $"{version}.xslt"));
        xsltTransform.Transform(xmlReader, writer);
        result = writerStream.ToArray();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Docker - 18.09.9
Net Core - 2.2
Docker container - Linux

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: 0x00 is indeed an invalid XML character. Please do check you what `encoding.GetString(report)` returns.

Comment: I checked it, encoding.GetString(report)  always return is correct xml.

Comment: Also I'am tried use XmlConvert.IsXmlChar() for checks

Comment: So where do you get the error? On the `Transform` call? Is that "sometimes" it throws the exception in any way related to a particular XML input and/or a particular XSLT code? Or does even the same set of XML and XSLT sometimes work fine in the docker container and sometimes not?

Comment: On the `Transform` call. Same set of XML and XSLT

Comment: I'm confused by the lines ```at <xsl:template name="compiler:generated"> (2)(XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator , String , String , String , IList`1 , String )
   at <xsl:template name="compiler:generated">(XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator )
   at <xsl:template match="/">(XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator )```

Comment: Please check again. The null character would probably display as a space. Also check that the byte array indeed represents the 1251 encoding. If it's e.g. Utf-16, then you will have that error. Just dump the content of `byte[] report` to a file and open it in Notepad++.

Comment: I got the dump and looked it up, the file is completely in 1251. There are no hidden symbols. Only spaces and line breaks. I can't understand why the same set of XML and XSLT files are 100% successful if I run the application not in a container

Comment: Your strings are probably one byte characters terminated with a '\0' (0x00).  So I suspect you are reading past the end of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error I wrote a file with xml to disk, and then loading by means of XslCompiledTransform.Load()

```
public byte[] Translate(byte[] report)
{
     var tempFolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
     Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolder);
     var reportPath = Path.Combine(tempFolder, "report.xml");
     var resultPath = Path.Combine(tempFolder, "result.xml");

     File.WriteAllBytes(reportPath, report);
     var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);

     var version = GetVersion(report, encoding);
     var xsltTransform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
     xsltTransform.Load(Path.Combine(shemesPath, $"{version}.xslt"));
     xsltTransform.Transform(reportPath, resultPath);

     return File.ReadAllBytes(resultPath);
}
```